# How to execute an action when textbox's content has changed?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two actions like:

Function `getNews`: to get list news.

Function `searchNews`: to get list news base on a keyword.

I create a form to submit that:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="getNew" action="<?php echo admin_url('Xpathnews/searchKeyword') ?>" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h4><b>Select your news</b></h4>
    <select id="selectcate" name="selectcate" class="field-custom">
      <option  value="http://theverge.com">The Verge</option>
      <option  value="http://neowin.net">Neowin</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h4><b>Keyword:</b></h4>
    <input name="search_keyword" id="search_keyword" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your keyword..." />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <input name="xpath_title" id="xpath_title" type="hidden" />
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <input  name="get_news" type="submit" id="get_news" value="Get News"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Or fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/f7zy0694/2/

I want when the user types any text in textbox `search_keyword`. Will execute action `searchNews`.

Usually, the user only clicks button `Get News` default execute action `getNews`.

I tried a solution in my controller/action:

```
public function getNews(){
        $xpath_title = $this->input->post('xpath_title');
}

public function searchNews() {
    $keyword = $this->input->post('search_keyword');
    if(empty($keyword)) {
      $this->getNews();
    } else {
        // execute my code at here
    }
}
```

... is check if `$keyword` don't have value it will execute function `$this->getNews` but problem is:

I have some `<input>` hidden, seem the call to function `getNews` it not working.

I also tried with `seft:redirect("/getNews")`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the combination of `ajax` and jquery `keyUp` event. An ajax call will be fired and bring data for you from `php` when somebody change the content of textbox

Comment: @SahilGulati I think to have another method simple more than using `ajax`.

Comment: @SahilGulati—no jquery tag or use in example code. jQuery is not required to use AJAX.

Comment: Have you considered a change listener on the textarea that, when the textarea content changes, changes the form's action?

Comment: Yes @RobG. Only need textbox changed. Form action(`searchNews`) will change. If the user deletes text in the textbox, it will execute default action(`getNews`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that you can use `Jquery` `ajax` with `keyUp` or `keyDown` like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchbox_id').keyUp(function(){
        // get the user entered string
        var searchTxt = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process_file.php',                        
            type: 'get',                                  
            data: {
                searchTxt  :searchTxt
            },
            success: function(response){
                // do your stuff here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mayank pandeyz.